# Connecting the definition of ambient isotopy to the intuition

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

I'm trying to understand why ambient isotopies are defined the way they are for knot theory.

**Definitions**: my text defines an isotopy between embeddings $f_1, f_2$ from $X$ to $Y$ as a continious map $F: X \times [0,1] \to Y \times [0, 1]: (x, t) \mapsto (f(x, t), t)$ such that $f(x, 0) = f_0(x)$ and $f(x, 1) = f_1(x)$. The intuition behind this is that $F$ continiously deforms the two embeddings into each other. This makes sense to me.

An ambient isotopy between $f_0$ and $f_1$ is defined as a continious map $H: Y \times [0, 1] \to Y \times [0, 1]: (y, t) \mapsto (h(y, t), t)$ such that $h(y, 0) = y$ and $h(f(x, 0), 1) = f(x, 1)$. The intuition is that $H$ defines an isotopy (by $F: (x, t) \mapsto (h(f(x, 0), t), t)$) that also preserves the ambient space around the embeddings. My precise questions are:

1. Why are two knots equal if they are ambient isotopic?
2. Why do we define $h$ the way we do?
3. Why does the $F$ defined by $H$ respect the ambient space?

Comment: What's your reference ?

Comment: @Sou Sorry, what does 'your reference' mean? My level of knowledge is one course in topology (20 hours a week, for 10 weeks, where we covered the basic topological properties such as homeomorphisms, constructions of topologies and some topological invariants) and the basic definitions of knot theory.

Comment: I mean what textbook did you use ?

Comment: @Sou Burde and Zieschang for knot theory, but I'm only a couple of pages in, and lecture notes for topology

Comment: Perhaps this will help you understand a bit why this definition is used: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336275/which-two-knots-are-isotopic-but-not-ambient-isotopic/1336396#1336396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that you have a sheet of thin rubber lying on your desk, so it's basically $I \times I$. It's taped down around its edge. You draw on it, in magic marker, a circle.

If you now put a finger in the center of the rubber sheet and tug it a little to one side, your circle may distort a bit, perhaps becoming egg-shaped. To a topologist, this is still a "circle in a rectangle". One reason is that it's easy to undo the operation -- you ease up on the sheet and it deforms back to what it looked like before. Such an operation is called an "isotopy" of the ambient space. In this example, $Y$ is the rubber sheet, and the motion induced by your finger is a sequence of mappings of $Y$ to itself: each piece of the rubber sheet moves (over a brief period of time) to a new location that happens to be a location where some rubber sheet was before.

What about the drawing? Well, that's an embedding of the circle into $Y$, and as $Y$ 'slides around within itself', the drawing gets carried along. You *could* define the knot to simply be the point set where the ink happens to be, but I assume that your text has made clear that things get simpler if we regard the map (i.e., the *parameterization* of the point-set by a circle) rather than the point-set itself. So when I say the drawing corresponds to the knot, what I really mean is that a parameterization of the drawing corresponds to the map $f$ in your definition.

With a homotopy of $f$, you could change the image of $f$ from a circle to, say, a figure $8$, or a single point. With an isotopy of $Y$, you can only change it to a distorted circle. That seems to better capture the notion that two knots are "the same" (in the sense that the knot used to tie *your* shoelaces is the same as the one used to tie *my* shoelaces, assuming that in each case we glue the tips together to get a circular shoelace (i.e., an embedding of $S^1$ rather than of $I$), even though your shoes and mine are not in exactly the same location.

Comment: What if you require the homotopy to remain an injective function from $S^1$ to $\Bbb{R}^3$ at all times, would you still be able to get a figure 8 knot from a regular circle? Can you perhaps direct me to a proof/visualization of this fact?

Comment: I didn't say anything about a figure-8 knot; I was talking about the appearance of the numeral 8 in most standard fonts, i.e., a 2D shape that crosses itself at one point. Since this is not the image of an injective (continuous) function from $S^1$ to $\Bbb R^3$, it clearly can't be arrived-at by the kind of homotopy you describe.