# Every tame knot is isotopic to the unknot.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, knot-theory

I am struggling to prove that every knot is isotopic to the unknot. Can someone please point me towards a reference of a proper proof? My attempt is as follows.

$\newcommand{\rthree}{\mathbf{R}^3}$
Let $K \subset \rthree$ be a knot.

Let $p \in K$. Take a ball $U_p \subset \rthree$ of radius $\varepsilon$ around the point $p$ such that the pair $(U_p, U_p \cap K)$ is homeomorphic to $(B, d)$, where $B$ is the unit ball in $\rthree$ centered at origin and $d$ is the diameter of $B$ along the $x$-axis. Such a ball exists as each point of the knot is locally flat. We choose a parametrization $f: [0, 2 \pi) \rightarrow K$ of the knot such that $f ([a, b]) = K \setminus (U_p \cap K)$, where $[a, b] \subset [0, 2 \pi)$.

Let $r \in \rthree$ be point outside $U_p$, i.e. $r \notin U_p$. Now consider the function $i_t \colon K \rightarrow \rthree$ defined for each $t \in [0, 1]$ as follows.
$$
  i_t (f(x)) =
  \begin{cases}
   f(x) & \text{if \(f(x) \in U_p\)} \\
   \displaystyle f(a) + t\left[tr + (1-t)f\left(a + t\left(\frac{b-a}{2} - a\right)\right) - f(a)\right] & \text{if $\displaystyle x \in \Bigg[a, a + t \left[\frac{b-a}{2} - a\right]\Bigg)$} \\
   t r + (1-t) f(x) & \text{if $\displaystyle x \in \Bigg[a + t \left[\frac{b-a}{2} - a\right], b -t\left[b - \frac{b-a}{2}\right]\Bigg]$} \\
   \displaystyle t r + (1-t) f\left(b - t\left(b- \frac{b-a}{2}\right)\right) + t\left[f(b) - t r - (1 - t) f\left(b - t\left(b- \frac{b-a}{2}\right)\right)\right] & \text{if $\displaystyle x \in \Bigg(b - t\left[b - \frac{b-a}{2}\right], b\Bigg]$}
  \end{cases}
  $$
Let $i \colon [0, 1] \times K \rightarrow \rthree$ be a function defined by $i(t, f(x)) := i_t(f(x))$. My intention is to define $i$ such that it keeps the part inside $U_p$ the same and shrinks the outside part. The end points of the shrunk part and the part inside $U_p$ are joined linearly.

I am not able to prove that $i$ is an isotopy.

Assuming it is, $U_p \cap K$ is straight line isotopic to the line joining $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Let this isotopy be $s$. $(s \circ i) (1, K)$ is a triangle with the vertices $r$, $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. This triangle is isotopic to $\mathbf{S}^1$.

How do I go about proving that $i$ is indeed an isotopy? I don't have trouble understanding that each $i_t$ is bjiective and continuous. The pre-image of an open set in $\mathbf{R}^3$ is equal to the pre-image of the intersection of the image of all $i_t$s with the open set. Now, I would have to prove that this pre-image is of the form $(A, f(C))$, where $A$ and $C$ are an open sets in $[0,1]$ and $[0, 2 \pi)$ respectively, right? $C$ is open iff $f(C)$ is open.

[image: K]
[image: i_t(K)]

---

By local flatness, I mean the following. A point $p \in K$ is said to be locally flat if there exists a neighbourhood $U_p \ni p$ such that the ordered pair $(U_p, U_p \cap K)$ is homeomorphic to $(B, d)$, where $B \subset \mathbf{R}^3$ is the unit ball around origin and $d \subset B$ is the set of points along a diameter of the ball. A knot $K$ is said to be locally flat if all points are locally flat.

By isotopy, I mean a homotopy $i$ such that all the individual $i_t$s are bijective. I distinguish between isotopy and ambient isotopy, although people usually mean ambient isotopy when they mean isotopy in a knot theory context. By ambient isotopy, I mean $a \colon [0, 1] \times \mathbf{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^3$. The domain in the ambient isotopy is not $\mathbf{S}^1$ but rather $\mathbf{R}^3$. My terminology follows *Knots and Links* by Cromwell.

Comment: So the fact that it is an embedding for each $t$ is clear right? So you are worried about continuity?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes, continuity in the product topology

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your isotopy essentially sends everything outside of the locally flat neighbourhood to a single point $x$. Then we just need to check continuity for open sets containing $x$ since any other open set will be isolated from it so eventually the isotopy will be a standard arc outside the isolating neighbourhood of $x$. And for an open set $U$ containing $x$ it's preimage under the isotopy is the union of the preimages of the intersections of the isotopies with $U$. Notice that an open set intersects a simple closed curve in a countable union of open arcs.

Comment: My isotopy does not send all the part outside a locally flat neighborhood (atleast I don't intend to define it in such a way). At some intermediate $t$, some part of the domain out the locally flat neighborhood (lcn) is mapped to straight lines. Some part is mapped to the "knotted" part. The part which is mapped to the knotted part shrinks as $t$ increases. The domain which maps to the knotted part decreases, as well as the image of the isotopy (in 3D space) decreases as $t$ increases.

Comment: @amd1234 sorry for the late reply. Comment ^

Comment: Okay but do you see why if you shrink everything outside your locally flat neighbourhood to a point this is continuous and is shows isotopy to the unknot?

Comment: @amd1234 Sorry, I don't understand that. If one shrinks everything outside a locally flat nbd. then we would need to deform the arc inside the nbd. such that the arms of the arc join at a point on the boundary of the nbd.; So $i_1$ would be a tear drop shaped figure with the top vertex being the vertex at which everything outside the nbd. is shrunk. Right?

Comment: For convenience i'm gonna work in $S^3$. Let $U_p$ be the tame neighbourhood, assume $U_p$ is an open 3-ball so its complement in $S^3$ is a closed 3-ball $B$. Let $A=B\cap K$ where $K$ is your knot and denote $a,b$ the intersection of $K$ with the boundary of $B$. Next there is a family of homeomorphisms $h_i: S^3\rightarrow S^3$ that are constant outside $Int(B)$ and shrink everything in $Int(B)$ closer and closer to point $x\in A\setminus \{a,b\}$ (for example by radial contraction)

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis btw i just realised there is a problem in your question: a knot is tame if it is locally tame at each point this is a consequence of a theorem by Bing and a tame knot is ambiently isotopic to the unknot by definition. What you are trying to show is that if a knot is locally tame at one point then it is topologically isotopic to the unknot

Comment: @amd1234 please check if I have understood what your first comment meant. I want to understand how does the family of homeomorphisms act on the part of domain (domain of $f$) which initially maps outside $U_p$. Does $h_t \circ f ([a, b])$ map outside $U_p$ for all $t$? If that is the case, then at $t=1$, it won't be injective as whole of $[a,b]$ will map to a single point, right? Or does the part of domain of $h_t \circ f$ which maps outside $U_p$ decrease as $t$ increases?

Comment: Re. second comment, I see. My definition (from Cromwell) doesn't seem to be the standard one. Is is equivalent though? Can you point to some references? Also, which theorem by Bing? If a knot is locally flat at one point then it is topologically isotopic (not ambient) to the unknot. Does this mean that a wild knot which has a locally flat nbd. is also top. isotopic to the unknot? Can you please give some references for this?

Comment: Each $h_i$ fixes the boundary of $B$ so $a,b$ remain fixed

Comment: Sorry it is not a theorem of Bing it is actually Brown. For some reason I thought it was Bing. I beleive the paper is called Locally Flat Imbeddings of Topological Spaces. It has a diagram on page 2 which shows locally flat is equivalent to flat. His definition of locally flat is the same Cromwell's and I believe that definition is what you will find in much literature. But I wish to distinguish locally flat from flat so I don't require local flatness everywhere (which by Brown is the same as flatness)

Comment: @amd1234 if $a$ and $b$ remain fixed then won't the whole of $[a, b]$ map to a single point eventually, thus breaking injectivity? I'll see the paper by Brown. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll collect what i wrote in the comments

Let $K\subset S^3$ be a knot that is locally flat at some point $p\in K$. Then let $U_p$ be the neighbourhood of $p$ s.t. $(U_p,U_p\cap K)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$ is a homeomorphism of pairs.

Then let $B = S^3\setminus U_p \cong D^3$, $A= B\cap K$ and $\{a,b\}=\partial B \cap K$. Then $A$ is a possibly wild arc with endpoints $\{a,b\}$ whilst its complement $I=K\setminus A$ is a tame arc. Thus we may pick another 3-ball $B'$ which contains $B$ in its interior, intersects $I$ in two points $\{a',b'\}$ and so $ K\cap (B'\setminus B)= J_a\cup J_b$ where $J_a$ and $J_b$ are tame arcs with end points $a,a'$ and $b,b'$ respectively.

Consider homeomorphisms $h_i:B' \rightarrow B'$ that is constant on $\partial B'$ but shrinks everything in the interior by a factor of $\frac{1}{i}$ for $i\in (0,1]$ to some point i will call $0\in Int(B)\cap K$. Extend this by identity to $H_i:S^3\rightarrow S^3$.

Fix $K$ as subset of $S^3$ and let us look at what this map does to $K$. For $i=1$ it doesn't move $K$ at all but as $i\rightarrow 1$ the arcs $J_a$ and $J_b$ get stretched towards $0\in B$ so that in the limit we get that image of  is a tame arc plus two straight line segments which are the images of $J_a$ and $J_b$ (this makes a tear shape as you say). Note that $a'$ and $b'$ stay fixed but $a$ and $b$ get closer and closer to $0$.

Let $f: S^1\rightarrow S^3$ be the embedding of the knot $K$. Then define an isotopy $I_i=H_i\circ f$ for $i\in (0,1]$ and $I_0(x)= \varinjlim I_i(x)$ for $x\in S^1\setminus f^{-1}(0)$ and $I_0(f^{-1}(0))= 0$ then $I_1$ is continuous and injective. Clearly all other $I_i$'s are also continuous and injective (and therefore embeddings).

Can you see why here continuity in the product holds? (An open set interestcs a simple closed curve in a countable union of open arcs - as the simple closed curve moves continuously the sizes of the arcs also change continuously).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your construction of isotopy is almost similar to the one I describe. I don't have any problem understanding that. Reg. the continuity in the product topology, I also understand what you write in the last paragraph, but I am struggling to give a _clear, rigirous proof_ of the same. The intersection of the image of a particular $I_i$ would be a with an open set in $S^3$ would be a countable collection of open arcs, and as we vary $i$, it would span a surface-like set. The pre-image of such a surface-like set should be open in the product top., right?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you too much.

Comment: There might be a neater way to do this but you can try the following. Let's deal with the case when $I_i(K)$ intersects $U$ in exactly one component from time $t_1$ to time $t_2$. Then let $x\in U\cap I_i(K)$ for some $i\in I_i(K)$. Can you construct an open set of the form $(x_1,x_2)\times (t_1',t_2')$ with $t_1<t_1', t_2'<t_2$ and $I_i^{-1}(x)\in [x_1,x_2]$ that contains $I_i^{-1}(x)$ and lies in the priemage of $U$ under the entire isotopy? Then you need to deal with the edge cases $I_0,I_1$ separately. When the intersection is a countable collection extend the above inductively

Comment: Does the following sketch make any sense? 
Let $t_0$ be such that $A := I_{t_0} (K) \cap U$ is a single component arc inside $U$. Let $X_0 \in A$. $X_0$ is an interior point in $U$. $A$ is open in the subset topology and thus $X_0$ is an interior point in $A$ as well. The pre-image of an open neighbourhood $B$ in $A$ is open by continuity of the isotopy in one component. Let the pre-image of this pre-image under $f$ be $(x_1, x_2) \subset [0, 2\pi)$. Thus, $I_{t_0}(f(x_1, x_2)) = B$.

Comment: contd. Take an $\epsilon$ neighbourhood tube $C$ around $B$ in $U$. For a point $X \in B$, consider the set $S$ of all $t$ such that $I_t(I_{t_0}^{-1}(X))$ is inside this tube $C$. $S$ is open. For each $X$, we shall get an open set $(t_{1, X}, t_{2, X})$. Now, union of all such open intervals for all $X$ inside $B$ is an open set. Thus, for each open set $U$, and for each interior point inside $U$, we can create an open subset of $U$ such that the pre-image of this open subset is open. We can take the union of the all the pre-images for all points inside $U$. This will be an open set.

Comment: I was ill so could not reply.

Comment: Your argument is a bit confusing to follow. Any point of $A$ (as you define it) is by definition an interior point. Also for each fixed $t$, $I_t$ is a homeomorphism so you can automatically assume you have an arc  $(x_1,x_2)\subset S^1=[0,1]/\{0,1\}$ homeomorphic to a proper open subarc of $A$ which you call $B$. But looks like the idea is correct

Comment: One person pointed out to me that $i$ is linear in one component and continuous in the other. This implies continuity in the product topology.